# R programming Neural network Forecasting

Tags: r, neural-network, forecasting

I'm having 3 problems with my code.

First is, understanding the differences between stepmax and backprop functions when implementing my neural net in RStudio.

The second problem is that I don't know how to compare the 2 neural net models as I'm trying to figure out which is the best model to use for predicting. Can someone please explain how I can use these two models to find out which is more precise as a model?

I'm using electrical hour consumption for 7 days which are my input nodes and I'm trying to predict the next 24 hours of the 8th day. I am confused on what do I do after I have these models so I can predict the next day? Please can someone help me?

```
street.model4 <- neuralnet(formula = D8 ~ D1 + D2 + D3 + 
                             D4 + D5 + D6 + D7, 
                           data = street.train, hidden = 4, stepmax=1e9) 


plot(street.model4)

street.model5 <- neuralnet(formula = D8 ~ D1 + D2 + D3 + 
                             D4 + D5 + D6 + D7, 
                           data = street.train, hidden = 4, learningrate = 0.01,
                           algorithm = "backprop", err.fct="ce",
                           linear.output=FALSE) #iterate


plot(street.model5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend looking in to some tutorials or texts regarding neural networks and machine learning in general.  There are several points here that require more detail than can be provided in a single SO answer.  To answer you questions as succinctly as possible.

1. 'backprop' functions? - 'backprop' is the algorithm you selected for the network to use for the weight update process.  It is the most simple algorithm and likely not what you want to use when there are more sophisticated algorithms like `RMSPROP`.
2. 'stepmax'? - as per the documentation, `stepmax` is the maximum number of iterations the algorithm will run before stopping if it doesn't converge first.  Another term you will see for this instead of `step` is `epoch`.
3. Which model is better? - you should look in to `cross-validation` depending upon the size of your data.  Essentially you want to train your different models on a `training` dataset and evaluate them on a final `test` dataset.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman, I have looked a great deal online before posting here, 1 and 2 are great answers. I have a problem with the 3rd because I've implemented cross validation but unfortunately I am not sure how I can get the training dataset and the final test dataset? Is there any programming examples that you could suggest for small forecasting load?